# Can the color aware LED backlighting for HDTV give a better User Experience?

Tags: interaction-design, user-research, experience, customer-experience

There are products that let you install LED lights behind your HDTVs so that it matches the colors on the shows that you watch and projects the light on the wall behind.

*e.g. **www.ambiscreen.tv, www.lightpack.tv***

Is it a better UX? Can it enhance your TV viewing experience?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - It is because it helps to decreases eye fatigue, but also helps make grays and blacks on your screen seem richer. It is called bias lighting:

https://www.avforums.com/article/do-i-need-bias-mood-lighting-tv.10747

http://www.howtogeek.com/213464/how-to-decrease-eye-fatigue-while-watching-tv-and-gaming-with-bias-lighting/

http://lifehacker.com/why-bias-lighting-increases-your-tvs-contrast-and-saves-1695117890